# Apply CSS Moving Transition to element with `transform` property

Tags: css, css-animations, transition

I want to apply CSS move transition to element with `transform` property.

Before transition:

```html
<ul class="list">
  <li>one</li>
  <li>two</li>
  <li>three</li>
</ul>
```

After transition:

```html
<ul class="list">
  <li>two</li>
  <li>three</li>
  <li>one</li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```css
.list > li {
  transform: skewX(15deg);
  transform-origin: bottom left;
}
```

I tried to apply `transition: transform 1s`, then `skewX` was also reset and re-applied.

Example video here: https://youtu.be/n3qC3uny5uM

How can I apply transition to only movement, not shape transform?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like following using CSS Animation.

```css
.container {
  background: #f7f8f9;
  display: flex;
}

.container div {
  width: 40px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #fcc700;
  margin: 0 4px;
  animation: spin linear 1.2s;
  // animation: spin linear 1s infinite;
}

@keyframes spin {
  from {
    transform: translateX(-50px);
  }
  to {
    transform: translateX(50px) skewX(-15deg);
    
  }
}
```

```html
  <div class="container">
    <div>A</div>
    <div>B</div>
  </div>
```